# Return all fields from API endpoint

Tags: clio-api

I might be blind and just not seeing it in the documentation, but is there a parameter that I can pass in that will return all the fields available in an endpoint instead of having to list out all of the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for the same thing when I started working with the API and I don't believe it exists (if it does it's not documented). Whatever fields you explicitly call for are the ones that you get back (if you call for none you get ID and ETAG only).

Whatever solution you come up with for your application, one thing to keep in mind is that if you include a field in the call which doesn't exist on the model, e.g. ask for a field called `document` on a matter, the entire call will return nothing. So, you can't, for instance, just request all the fields from the entire API, which would be convenient, but you could build up a list of all the fields which occur on a particular subsection. I ended up doing something like that for subfields (which are also not returned unless specifically asked for, which is annoying).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm guessing the answer is no, but do you know if there's a way to get a list of fields for the Custom Fields?  My company is currently trying to build out an integration with Clio, and we're hoping to build it so it can be done as dynamically as possible to streamline the process for different clients with the different fields that they may have.

Comment: Sorry, your guess is correct :( Custom fields will always come as an array of objects though so if you remap to k/v pairs you should be able to generalize it to whatever is consuming the response. I just finished a project where the client had over 200 custom fields, it was an adventure. My Twitter link is in my profile. Feel free to get in touch if you have other questions.

Comment: @RobertStovall I was wrong about custom fields, you can get all of them here: `api/v4/custom_fields?fields=name,id,parent_type,field_type,deleted` this will give you all the fields in the DB as well as their ID #s so you can target them

Comment: Thanks.  Saw that in my third go around with the documentation.  Was too focused on the main objects.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is ?fields= at the end for return all fields

[?fields= returns all with no value needed for a wild card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxuqP.png)

[?fields= returns all with no value needed for a wild card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J2tQ.png)

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text / code.